# Spring data MongoOperations vs Mongocollection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Mongodb Java driver. My Mongodb version is 3.4.2 and MongoDB Java driver version 3.4.2. I am using Spring Data Release Train Ingalls (I think this is the latest version).

I see that the Spring Data MongoOperations class uses DBCOllection, DBObject classes in it's API.
Referring to another answer on SO, I see that its recommended that we shouldn't be using DBCollection and other similar classes going forward and instead use MongoCollection etc. (This answer is by Driver's author himself)

[MongoCollection versus DBCollection java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364787/mongocollection-versus-dbcollection-java)

As a result, I am very confused now whether should I be using MongoCollection class directly or Spring data classes like MongoOperations ( Spring Data has lot of other helper classes for deserializing/serializing etc)
Some of the features like projections are not available on old classes like DBCollection.

Can anyone please help? What is the recommended approach, should I be using Spring Data's classes like MongoOperations or MongoCollection etc.

Regards,
V

Answer (score 1):

The current release 1.10.0 doesn't have support for Mongo 3.x classes.

The upcoming spring 2.0.0 release has support for 3.x classes. So you can use all the newer classes with `MongoOperations`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#new-features.2-0-0

Comment: Thanks. That's makes sense. I did check the link provided. Looks like post release of version 2.0.0 I should have what I am after.